# Using Servant.Elm and Elm.Derive with Int64 (deriving and generating definition for an unboxed type) causes an Elm syntax error

Tags: haskell, elm, servant

I'm trying to use [Servant.Elm](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-elm-0.7.2/docs/Servant-Elm.html) and [Elm.Derive](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/elm-bridge-0.6.1/docs/Elm-Derive.html#t:Options) to generate an Elm Api from a Haskell Servant Api including `Int64` which I learnt is [defined](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Int.html#I64%23) as a primitive unboxed Haskell type:

```
data {-# CTYPE "HsInt64" #-} Int64 = I64# Int#
```

In the generated Elm module the Haskell type `Int64` is represented by the following Elm type:

```
type Int64  =
    I64# Int#
```

, which is not valid Elm syntax:

```
-- UNEXPECTED SYMBOL  /Users/XXX/elm-frontend/src/Derived.elm

I got stuck on this symbol:

14|     I64# Int#
           ^
It is not used for anything in Elm syntax. Try removing it?
```

I cannot find an easy way to configure this with the [ElmOptions](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-elm-0.7.2/docs/Servant-Elm.html#t:ElmOptions).
Is this a bug or a missing feature in the [Servant.Elm](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-elm-0.7.2/docs/Servant-Elm.html) package? Or, are there other reasons why I should stay away from `Int64` in my Servant API?

Even if I could rewrite my Servant Api to use something else than `Int64` or manually write Elm code for everything related to routes using `Int64` I would like to know if there is a way to derive/generate a valid Elm definition for `Int64` or other Haskell types with `#` as constructor suffix and/or type suffix.

An attempt at a minimal test case:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell   #-}

module DeriveElmTest where

import Data.Proxy
import Servant.API (EmptyAPI)
import Data.Int (Int64)
 
import Elm.Derive (
   defaultOptions
 , deriveElmDef
 )

import Servant.Elm (
   DefineElm (DefineElm)
 , Proxy (Proxy)
 , defElmImports
 , defElmOptions
 , generateElmModuleWith
 )
 
deriveElmDef defaultOptions ''Int64
  
main :: IO ()
main =
  generateElmModuleWith
    defElmOptions
    [ "Derived"]
    defElmImports
    "elm-frontend/src"
    [ DefineElm (Proxy :: Proxy Int64)]
    (Proxy :: Proxy EmptyAPI)
```

, which produces the following Elm module:

```
module Derived exposing(..)

import Json.Decode
import Json.Encode exposing (Value)
-- The following module comes from bartavelle/json-helpers
import Json.Helpers exposing (..)
import Dict exposing (Dict)
import Set
import Http
import String
import Url.Builder

type Int64  =
    I64# Int#

jsonDecInt64 : Json.Decode.Decoder ( Int64 )
jsonDecInt64 =
    Json.Decode.lazy (\_ -> Json.Decode.map I64# (jsonDecInt#))


jsonEncInt64 : Int64 -> Value
jsonEncInt64 (I64# v1) =
    jsonEncInt# v1
```

Comment: I suspect the real problem here is going to be the `Int#`, not the `I64#`. With some work, you should be able to make whatever code generator is being used emit a valid data constructor name in place of `I64#`. But if Elm doesn't already have an analog for `Int#` then making the code generator do the right thing is going to be strictly more work than writing the code yourself without going through the generator.

Comment: @DanielWagner 
As far as I [understand](https://www.fpcomplete.com/haskell/tutorial/primitive-haskell/), in Haskell the type `Int#` is an unboxed built in primary type represented by a C long int. When you write "if Elm doesn't already have an analog for `Int#`" do you mean that Elm might not have the concept of unboxed types (faster?) or if Elm does not have an integer type of the same range? 

If Elm doesn't have the concept of boxed vs unboxed types, what would the problem be if the Haskell `Int#` would be represented by a "normal" Elm Int? And could this not be part of `Servant.Elm`?

Comment: I don't now much about the inner workings of neither Haskell nor Elm but this makes me curious to learn more.

Comment: I don't know Elm, but I know compilers. So I am writing about what I know. Exactly as you say, possibilities include "Elm does not have unboxed types" and "Elm does not have integer types of the same range" and more besides. It is unlikely that using an Elm `Int` to represent `Int#` would cause problems if Elm's `Int` has the same range and overflow behavior. But then, why bother with `I64#` and `Int#` in that case instead of just using the correspondence "`Int64` in Haskell" <-> "`Int` in Elm"?

Comment: Thanks @DanielWagner. This makes a lot of sense. I was playing around with a [Servant and PostgreSQL](https://mmhaskell.com/real-world/servant) tutorial and this Servant API was using `Int64`. When I start my own Servant project I will stay away from `Int64` in the Servant Api :-) But I have a feeling it could still be useful for `Servant.Elm` to be able to handle an arbitrary Servant API with data types such as `Int64` or similar.

Comment: I've posted the following `elm-bridge` GitHub issue: [How to deal with # (magic hash) in Haskell data types?](https://github.com/agrafix/elm-bridge/issues/51).